# How to increase capacity of open stack hypervisor local disks

Tags: openstack, devstack

I configured an open stack with devstack this time, but I think there will be a shortage of local storage, so I'm going to add it. So we have a 2TB hard drive that is composed of raid, so we're going to add it to the open stack, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about ephemeral storage, I believe Devstack puts that on `/opt/stack/data/nova/instances` (you may want to double-check that on your system). You would have to mount your disk there.

You may want to consider putting the entire /opt/stack onto the disk, since other large storage consumers such as Cinder and Swift would then have lots of space as well.

I am a bit worried. What are your plans with this Devstack? Note that Devstack is suitable for testing, experimenting and learning, but nothing else. Among other problems, a Devstack cloud can't be rebooted without manual intervention.

EDIT:

I would try it as follows:

- delete all instances
- stop Nova, e.g. `systemctl stop devstack@n-*`
- mount the hard drive somewhere, for example on /mnt/2tb
- copy /opt/stack/data/nova to the drive, e.g. `cd /opt/stack/data/nova; find . | cpio -pdumva /mnt/2tb`
- mount the 2TB drive on /opt/stack/data/nova

The first two steps are precautions against copying inconsistent data.

Better, reinstall that server, mount the 2TB drive on /opt, then rebuild the Devstack.

Note that only works if your instances use ephemeral storage. If they use volumes, you need to copy Cinder data instead of Nova.

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail?

We are currently conducting a simple test with devstack. We are planning to install it again with microstack and operate it later.

Comment: I added possible steps to the answer.